# Problema ao instalar Oracle XE e PHP 7 no Windows 10

Tags: oracle11g, php-7

Estou com problemas para resolver essa instalação.
Será que é relativo ao suporte o oracle ao Win10?

Tentei vários fóruns e não consegui.
Estou usando as DLLs diretamente do pecl.

Mas sempre tenho o mesmo erro:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Comment: Olha. Eu instalei o xampp e consegui de boas, no xampp é php 7

Comment: Vc precisou baixar alguma dll? Ou a que já se encontrava no xampp foi necessário? Sua versão do Windows é x64?

Comment: Não precisei baixar dll, O meu sistema operacional do Trabalho é Windows 10 64bits

Comment: Só precisei baixar o instantClient

Comment: Aqui não. Mas a única diferença é que não estou usando o Xampp.
Qual é a versão que vc está usando?

Comment: É. Porque já veio com tudo. A minha versão é v3.2.2

Comment: Eu tive problema quando era o Wamp php 5, ai fui tentar atualizar e não funcionou mais. Quando instalei apenas o xampp, funcionou rapdidinho

Comment: Qual você está usando? Wampserver?

Comment: Bitnami WAMP stack, com o php 7.0.27

Comment: Eu também tive problema com o Wampserver versão atualizada. Por isso a versão anterior